# which best, cookie or headers for sending JWT tokens?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt

which best for getting httpOnly cookies to the backend

get the cookies from frontend then send it to backend by `Header Authorization`

or

catch the cookies directly with backend ( without using `Header Authorization` )

because I don't know why I need to send it using Authorization headers

Comment: HttpCookie [ref](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)